# What is the best practice for looping through a dictionary of pandas dataframes and making modifications?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary of DataFrames with the key referring to the year of the data. I would like to iterate through the dict and make modifications to the DataFrames. I make modifications to both the column names and the contents of the dfs.

```
for year, df in df_data.items():
    cols = df .columns
    new_cols = [re.sub(r'\s\d{4}\-\d{2}', '', c) for c in cols]
    df.columns = new_cols

for year, df in df_data.items():
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Id', keep='first')
```

Can someone explain to me the behavior of doing this? Particularly, how the dfs are stored in memory and why the rename of columns works but the modification to the contents do not. 
Also, is there a best way to do this either by copying the df and then replacing it in the dict index or by constantly making the changes to the df_data[year] reference?

Comment: Please show us what result you're getting and what the issue is. The code you've posted should work.

Comment: Hi Dave, Sorry, I have added to the code in the second for loop. In particular, a df.drop_duplicates(). This does no update the df in the dictionary, but does the for the df. Is this because a drop_duplicates creates a new 'view' slice of the original df in memory?

Comment: It creates *a new dataframe*. Use the `inplace=True` argument for it to work in-place

Comment: Yes, the inplace=True works because (I assume) it makes changes to the object in memory without returning a new reference to the dataframe in memory? I have my code set up right now to write the df reference back to the dict[idx] at the end of the loop. I was wondering what the best practice is for loopig through dfs in a dict and the specifics of how pandas works with the dfs in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @juanpa.arrivillaga describes above, `drop_duplicates` [returns a dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), which you're assigning to the local variable `df`. Consider the following example:

```
a = [0, 1]
for b in a:
    print(f'b: {b}')
    b = 2
    print(f'b: {b}') 

print(f'a: {a}')
```

This is the output:

```
b: 0
b: 2
b: 1
b: 2
a: [0, 1]
```

You can see that the local var `b` is being assigned the value `2`, but that the list `a` is unchanged after the loop completes. This is because `b` is a reference to the list, **not** the list itself. Assigning `b = 2` causes `b` to change to a reference to the integer `2`, but **does not** cause the list item that `b` refers to to change to a reference to the integer `2`.
At the start of the first loop, the references look like this:

```
b -> a[0] -> the integer 0
```

Assigning `b = 2` results in this:

```
a[0] -> the integer 0
   b -> the integer 2
```

**Not** this:

```
b -> a[0] -> the integer 2
```

To mutate an object in loop, you must work only with methods which work in place, or you must work with a direct reference to the object:

```
for year in df_data.keys():
    cols = df[year].columns
    new_cols = [re.sub(r'\s\d{4}\-\d{2}', '', c) for c in cols]
    df[year].columns = new_cols

for year in df_data.keys():
    df[year]['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[year]['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
    df[year] = df[year].drop_duplicates(subset='Id', keep='first')
```

Comment: Thanks, great explanation. This has helped.